# dual boot Windows/Linux "file not found error" appears before boot menu

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, ubuntu-11.10

I have recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 on a computer where I also have a Windows 7 installation, so I have a dual boot computer. Everything works fine, except the fact that before the boot menu appears, I get this error:

> file not found

and sometimes, I get this error when I boot into Windows, followed by

> Press any key to continue...

Both operating systems work fine but I am worried about these two errors I get.

Can anyone help me fix this error?

Where does this error come from?

Comment: Sounds like your boot loader has some invalid entries.  Which boot loader are you using?  What are your current boot loader configurations?

Comment: I currently have grub boot loader. What do you mean by "configurations"?